In laravel Dompdf not displaying other language
I'm trying to display Japanese font using dompdf in laravel. I'm not using any laravel package. Using directly DomPDF
Here is my effort

public function pdfView()
    {
         // Load HTML content with @font-face rule
         $html = '
         <style>
             @font-face {
                 font-family: "NotoSansJP"; /* Define the font family */
                 src: url("/fonts/NotoSansJP-Bold.ttf") format("truetype"); /* Specify the URL of the font file */
             }
             body { 
                 font-family: "NotoSansJP", sans-serif; /* Use the font family */
             }
         </style>
         <h1>ウェブネーションは自社サービスを企画から</h1>';

        $fontDir = public_path('/fonts');
        $options = new Options();
        $options->setFontDir($fontDir);
        $options->setDefaultFont('NotoSansJP');
     
        // Create Dompdf instance
        $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
    
        // Load HTML content
        $dompdf->loadHtml($html, 'UTF-8');
    
        // Render PDF
        $dompdf->render();
    
        // Get the PDF content
        $pdfContent = $dompdf->output();
    
        // Set response headers to display PDF inline
        return response($pdfContent)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
            ->header('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="abc.pdf"')
        ;
    }


In 2 ways I have tried to change font using font-face and also by dompdf options.
But in both case result is same

I have saved all .ttf file into public/fonts location

Then what I'm missing here ?
